# Why isn't this sed command working for the regex?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I want to remove the multi-line comments in `Java` using `sed` command. The regex is working if we use character ranges like `a-zA-Z0-9` etc. but not in case of word character like `\w\S`.

Test-File content:

```
hello world
/* abcd
efgh*/
world hello
```

Command used :

```
sed -i -e  "s/\/\*[\s\S]\*\///" <file>
```

Expected results:

```
hello world
world hello
```

Actual results:

```
hello world
 abcd
efgh*/
world hello
```

Comment: It won't work because by default `sed` searches and replaces on separate lines and `[\s\S]` does not match any char in POSIX regex, it matches either ``\``, `s` or `S` (also, you did not even attempt to quantify it, so it would not work even in online regex testers).

Comment: Why don't try to remove every line that starts with `/*`, and every line that ends with `*/`

Comment: Easy mode: `perl -i -0777 -pe 's!/\*.*?\*/!!sg'`. That said, this approach doesn't work because it doesn't take `// comments` or `"string literals"` into account.

Comment: Worked well, thanks @melpomene. I guess I should look into the performance comparison too.

Comment: It'll miss the multiline comments that are put in the middle of a line statement @HamzaAbdaoui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) with a regex (`-E`) and inverted matches (`-v`), i.e.:

```
grep -Ev '(\/\*|\*\/)' < text.txt
```

**Output:**

```
hello world
world hello
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with sed, but not so easy.

```
sed ':x ; /^\/\*/ { N ; s/.*\*\/// ; /^$/d ; bx }' file
```

- `:x` is a label
- `/^\/\*/` is /*
- `N` append line from the input to the pattern space
- `s/.*\*\///` replace any {...}*/
- `/^$/d` remove empty line
- `bx` jumps unconditional to :x

Find more here in the documentation

- [sed: Branching and flow control](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Branching-and-flow-control.html#Branching-and-flow-control)
- [sed: Multiline technique](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Multiline-techniques.html#Multiline-techniques)